# How can I dynamically render input fields with condition?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic

I am trying to use less code and dynamically render input fields. I've got this dynamic output of 4 input fields and I've got 4 name and amount states.

```
this.state = {
            input: {
                name1: '',
                name2: '',
                name3: '',
                name4: '',
                amount1: '',
                amount2: '',
                amount3: '',
                amount4: '',
            },
```

Here how I render 4 fields:

```
 {
        [1,2,3,4].map((i) => {
            return (
                <div>
                       <p>Name{i}</p>
                       <p>Amount:</p>
                  <div>
                    <Input
                      value={this.state.input[`name${i}`]}
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        this.updatePayee(`name${i}`, event.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                    </div>
                       <p>Amount:</p>
                  <div>
                    <NumberInput
                      value={this.state.input[`amount${i}`]}
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        this.updateAmount(`amount${i}`, event.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
        })
    }
```

How can I dynamically output 1,2,3,4 based on other state's condition?

```
{this.state.input.selection == "4" && (
    render 4 divs like above
 )}

 {this.state.input.selection == "3" && (
    render 3 divs like above
 )}

 {this.state.input.selection == "2" && (
    render 2 divs like above
 )}

 {this.state.input.selection == "1" && (
    render 1 divs like above
 )}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dinamically generate your array like so:

```
const elements = Array(this.state.input.selection).fill().map((v, i) => i + 1);
```

then use as you have now

```
elements.map(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```js
Array.from(Array(4), (_, i) => i+1).map(v => 
 Array.from(Array(v)).map((_,i) => {
  console.log(v+": "+i);
 })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[...Array(length)]` to render a dynamic number of elements :

```
 {
        [...Array(this.state.input.selection)].map((_,ind)=>ind+1).map((i) => {
            return (
                <div>
                       <p>Name{i}</p>
                       <p>Amount:</p>
                  <div>
           ...
```

`[...Array(size)]` gives an array of `size` undefined elements, in this case you need just the index.